# Why does this reducer function not work in a typescript class and can I make it work?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I've been playing around with reducers in this years's first advent of code challenge, and this code works fine:

```
export default class CalorieCounter {
  public static calculateMaxInventoryValue(elfInventories: number[][]): number {
    const sumInventoriesReducer = (
      acc: number[],
      element: number[]
    ): number[] => [...acc, this.sumCalories(element)];

    return Math.max(...elfInventories.reduce(sumInventoriesReducer, []));
  }

  private static sumCalories(inventory: number[]): number {
    return inventory.reduce((a: number, b: number) => a + b, 0);
  }
}
```

I then tried to split out the sumInventoriesReducer into it's own private function in the same class. This code does not work:

```
export default class CalorieCounter {
  public static calculateMaxInventoryValue(elfInventories: number[][]): number {
    return Math.max(...elfInventories.reduce(this.sumInventoriesReducer, []));
  }

  private static sumInventoriesReducer(
    acc: number[],
    element: number[]
  ): number[] {
    return [...acc, this.sumCalories(element)];
  }

  private static sumCalories(inventory: number[]): number {
    return inventory.reduce((a: number, b: number) => a + b, 0);
  }
}
```

The logic is exactly the same, all that's changed is that it's passed in as a private function (the fact that it's static isn't the reason, tried it without static and got the same error).

This is the error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'sumCalories' of undefined

      20 |     element: number[]
      21 |   ): number[] {
    > 22 |     return [...acc, this.sumCalories(element)];
         |                          ^
      23 |   }
      24 |
      25 |   private static sumCalories(inventory: number[]): number {
```

I want to do this in an OOP way if I can, aware reducers are a staple of functional programming but I feel like I should be able to get this work using a private class function. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to bind `this.sumInventoriesReducer`? `Math.max(...elfInventories.reduce(this.sumInventoriesReducer.bind(this), []));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access an instance property (that exist only after `constructor()` has been called) in a static method (that exists only on the class and not on the prototype).

After a `constructor()` method has been called the keyword `this` has the value of the `instance` object, but if you reference `this` in a static method you're referencing an undefined variable since to access a static method you don't call a constructor method

```
export default class CalorieCounter {
  public static calculateMaxInventoryValue(elfInventories: number[][]): number {
    return Math.max(...elfInventories.reduce(this.sumInventoriesReducer, []));
  }

  private static sumInventoriesReducer(
    acc: number[],
    element: number[]
  ): number[] {
    return [...acc, this.sumCalories(element)]; // The problem is here
  }

  private static sumCalories(inventory: number[]): number {
    return inventory.reduce((a: number, b: number) => a + b, 0);
  }
}
```

If you want to keep this schema you can just update that line so it would go

- from: `this.sumCalories(element)`
- to: `CalorieCounter.sumCalories(element)`
  By doing so, you're accessing the method from the class itself and not from a non-existing instance.

The resulting code would be:

```
export default class CalorieCounter {
  public static calculateMaxInventoryValue(elfInventories: number[][]): number {
    return Math.max(...elfInventories.reduce(this.sumInventoriesReducer, []));
  }

  private static sumInventoriesReducer(
    acc: number[],
    element: number[]
  ): number[] {
    return [...acc, CalorieCounter.sumCalories(element)]; // The problem is here
  }

  private static sumCalories(inventory: number[]): number {
    return inventory.reduce((a: number, b: number) => a + b, 0);
  }
}
```

Same as above, also the `calculateMaxInventoryValue` method is static but tries to access an instance method, by correcting it the code would become:

```
export default class CalorieCounter {
  public static calculateMaxInventoryValue(elfInventories: number[][]): number {
    return Math.max(...elfInventories.reduce(CalorieCounter.sumInventoriesReducer, []));
  }

  private static sumInventoriesReducer(
    acc: number[],
    element: number[]
  ): number[] {
    return [...acc, CalorieCounter.sumCalories(element)]; // The problem is here
  }

  private static sumCalories(inventory: number[]): number {
    return inventory.reduce((a: number, b: number) => a + b, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works fine now, thank you! I should probably read more into class lifecycles.

Comment: That's a delicate argument, might by confusing at first but it's actually really simple once mastered. Just take a look at instance and class methods

Answer (score -1):

This is because you don't flatten `this.sumCalories(element)`.

`this.sumCalories(element)` returns a `number[]`, so you need to flatten this with the three dots.

If you write `return [...acc, ...this.sumCalories(element)];` it should work.

Comment: `this.sumCalories(element)` returns a `number` not a `number[]`

Comment: `this.sumCalories` returns a number and that's not even close to the error printed in console